# iOS Sdk Adding Audio to a button on iPad?

Tags: ios, audio, button, ipad

My biggest problem at the moment: I have tried for days **to add a sound to a button** for my newest **iPad App** but it seems to be a different procedure than iphone. There are hardly any tutorials on how to do this? Any clues? Sample code I can borrow?

Please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D has a very good audio engine called CocosDenshion that you can import, then it's as simple as....

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playSoundEffect:@"soundEffect.caf"]
```

In your `buttonPressed:` method.